# Macro app script to double click on the cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, double-click

I have a pivot table in google sheet

[image]

When I double click on the numbers column the sheet with details is being opened.
I would like to record a macro to double click it for me.
Is it possible? Please assist?

```
function test() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('L8').activate();
};
```

I am stuck on selecting the right cell and I do not know how to write a code to double click this cell.

Comment: I am trying to double click the selected cell

Comment: I am trying to get the sheet with details related to pivot table - normally we get it by double clicking the cell with values in google sheets pivot table

Comment: Can you provide an example sheet to demonstrate what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Macros run in Google's servers, not in your computer, and have limited access to the user interface. You cannot send a double-click event but will have to find another means to get what you want.

For example, if you want to see details regarding a client name, such as `abcaccounting`, you can write a script that finds the client name in the active row in the pivot table, searches a data sheet for that name, and finally activates the cell in the data sheet that contains the client name.

To get the pivot tables in a sheet, use [Sheet.getPivotTables()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getpivottables). To get the data range of a pivot table, use [PivotTable.getSourceDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-table#getsourcedatarange). Here is an example of how to apply these methods:

```
function activatePivotTableDataRange() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getPivotTables()[0]
    .getSourceDataRange()
    .activate();
}
```